# pathForResource Question

Tags: objective-c

Hey guys, im getting a little trouble here.

First of all, i was using TBXML to parse some xml and add images address to an NSMUtableArray. Nice. Everythings works fine. But when i decided to put the images inner the app, i used this to add the images manually:

```
self.galeria =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[self.galeria addObject:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"001" ofType:@"jpg"]];

[self.galeria addObject:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"002" ofType:@"jpg"]];

[self.galeria addObject:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"003" ofType:@"jpg"]];

[self.galeria addObject:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"004" ofType:@"jpg"]];

[self.galeria addObject:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"005" ofType:@"jpg"]];

[self.galeria addObject:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"006" ofType:@"jpg"]];
```

Great. Instead of using an external xml, im just using the images from app. But the images arent appearing. I havent put the images in any folder, just in "Other Sources". Whats happening?

When i NSLog [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"006" ofType:@"jpg"] for example, it returns to me the complete path of file on my system. But doesnt works.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you get from NSLog(@"%@", self.galeria); The issue is the mutable array contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you won't be able to add the physical images into an array.

You should first create the UIImage objects with your stored images, and then collect them inside your array.

Answer (score 1):

self.galeria is an NSMutableArray of filepaths. When you NSLog(@"%@", self.galeria) you should see a list of all the image paths in the console. However, you're not actually instantiating UIImages from these paths. You'll need to use:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
```